# configure outgoing settings in email router (dynamics CRM 2011)

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to configure email router in dynamics CRM 2011

so, Could anyone explain me how to turn an outgoing profile there as well, please? ;)

I wonder with the follow setting:

Accsess credentials

there is a listbox, where you can choose an Other Specifed or an User Specifed value

The first one didn't work on my side cos I got an error:
"An error occurred while processing the outgoing e-mail message for ExchangeOnline:
The access credentials that you have specified have insufficient delegate permissions to send the e-mail message. Contact your Microsoft Exchange administrator to grant the required permissions".

So, I'm interested how to use the second one!?

I've found in docs that if I gonna you User Specifed then I should create an outgoing profile for each user, however I could find how to do it? Did anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for deployment you can set only one outgoing profile. In my case, for outgoing profile I'm using 'Other specified' access credentials. Here I set an administrator account. Also I've checked 'Send as permission'. Just note that this account must be granted 'Send As' permission. On [this link](http://msdynamicswiki.com/2012/05/04/an-error-may-occur-when-sending-on-behalf-of-or-sending-as-another-user-when-using-the-microsoft-dynamics-crm-email-router-with-office-365-exchange-online/) you can find more details.

Also be careful with certificates. They were mostly the cause of my troubles.

Comment: thanks, eventially solved by granting 'Send As' permissions to the account